# Swipe JS: click edge to next item

Tags: javascript, swipe.js

I'm using [Swipe JS](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe) to create a full screen image gallery and want to add the ability to click on the left / right edge to get to the previous / next slide.

I've tried creating absolutely positioned `a` tags but that breaks the swipe functionality because a swipe can't be initiated on the links.
To fix this I thought I could pass the event along to the correct element:

```
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    document.getElementById('swipe-wrap').dispatchEvent(e);
}, false);
```

But this throws the following error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.
```

Does anyone know how to pass along the event? Or maybe a better way to do this?